# Alternative field type in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json

Somebody made a very poor design decision and can deliver me a JSON that has an "exceptional" structure. To simplfy the problem:

```
{
    "messed-up": "string"
}

{
    "messed-up": { "nested": "value" }
}
```

Basically a field (very deeply hidden in my case) can be either a string or a more complex object. I need to create such a class structure that would allow me to:

- Perform serialization / deserialization
- Generate schema

Thus I would need something like this:

```
public class NotFunny
{
    [JsonProperty("messed-up", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string messedUp;

    [JsonProperty("messed-up", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Alternative messedUpAlternative;
}

public class Alternative
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string nested;
}
```

However, for obvious reasons, this cannot work. My question is: how to deal with this sad case?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `dynamic` type for this purposes.

[Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

My Sample with Newtonsoft.Json:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

dynamic data1 = JObject.Parse(str1);

if (data1.messed_up is JValue)
    Console.WriteLine(data1.messed_up);

if (data1.messed_up is JObject)
    Console.WriteLine(data1.messed_up.nested);
```

Comment: I also thought that it might work, unfortunately it doesn't work with schemas. It says "Invalid type. Expected Object, Null but got String".

Comment: I'll add one sample in few minutes. Hopefully it could help